# Using Android 2.3.4 (stock) as a WiFi Hotsport

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, wifi-hotspot

I am using Nexus S on Android 2.3.4 GingerBread. I'm setting it up as WiFi hotspot. I can connect other devices to this phone (they get an IP/subnet/gateway), but they can't access the internet. However, accessing the internet (3G) from my Android phone works fine though.

Any suggestion on how to proceed/analyze this issue?

Comment: With which cell carrier do you have a contract?

Comment: Cellcom (in Israel), I don't see how this is relevant, since I didn't get the phone from them, so they didn't have a chance to mess with it :-)

Comment: Carriers can block tethering if they so desire, so it's highly relevant.  Just ask anyone without a rooted device on Verizon in the USA.

Comment: ok, since I am a noob i'll take you word for it. Is there a way I can detect if they did block tethering (some setting I can look at)?

Comment: Unfortunately none that I know of.  I'd get in contact with your carrier if I were you, but don't let them know who you are.  Call from a payphone, give them a fake name, tell them you're not yet a customer but you're interested in their service, (however many steps safe you want to be) and ask them what their official policy on tethering is.  If you call from your phone they can ID you, and if you start asking about tethering and they happen to restrict it you may be putting yourself in their cross-hairs needlessly.  I couldn't find their website, so really you just need to do some research.

Comment: Possibly related: [Tethering an Android 2.2.1 (Froyo) using Wifi](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11158/tethering-an-android-2-2-1-froyo-using-wifi) (similar problem: IP and ping OK, but no Internet).