# Tethering an Android 2.2.1 (Froyo) using Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, internet, wifi-tethering

I'm trying to get tethering to work. I've used the built-in functionality, setup my phone as an AP and connected to the wireless network.

I get an IP (192.168.43.26) and I can ping the gateway (192.168.43.1), I also got a dns server (192.168.43.1). However, I can't access the internet (e.g. surf or ping 8.8.8.8).

Any ideas on what may be wrong?

**netstat -r (restricted to en1, the wireless interface)**

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.43.1       UGScI           0        0     en1
192.168.43         link#6             UCS             2        0     en1
192.168.43.1       4:18:f:40:41:7c    UHLWI           0       16     en1    925
192.168.43.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       12     en1
```

**Some more info**

- Using WPA2 Personal (since I can ping the phone/gateway/router I should be beyond the encryption layer in the OSI model, so I don't think encryption is the problem)
- Wireless AP
- No third-party tethering (using native)
- Samsung Galaxy
- No custom ROM
- Don't know if it's rooted (I guess the fact that I don't know means it isn't)

Comment: What do you mean by the router?  The "router" should be the phone in this setup.  Either way: Why is the address not 192.168.0.1?  What device do you have?

Comment: The router is OS X language for gateway (updated the question). The device is a Samsung Galaxy Gio (not locked to a particular carrier).

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is impossible because of https://android.stackexchange.com/a/14788/8059

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux, check up the kernel routing table by
typing **route** at terminal.

if you do not have a **default** entry in the list it won't work.
For example my kernel routing table reads:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.137.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
default         192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

Type in this command at terminal and see if it works:

*sudo route add default gw 192.168.43.1 wlan0*

where wlan0 is your wireless interface....

also you could try rechecking the dns server on your machine
and add the following lines to your **etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added a routing table. The DNS shouldn't be the problem since I can't even ping public IPs (such as 8.8.8.8)

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear up some terminologies here:

1. The phone acts is both a gateway (translates between Mobile network protocol and Wifi protocol) and a router (routes packets to and from other devices and the external link). I assume that your phone's IP address is 192.168.43.1. The phone have an internet connection through mobile data connection and want to share this connection with other devices.
2. The other devices (e.g. laptop) does not have direct internet connection, and is trying to tether through the gateway/phone. In your case, the other devices acquired the IP 192.168.43.26 through DHCP.

Are you using any encryption? WEP or WPA? I suggests setting up an open network for troubleshooting, and only setup encryption after you are able to connect through unencrypted connection. Check that the encryption setting and passphrase matches.

What tethering method are you using? Are you using third party tethering, e.g. PDANet or android-wifi-tether? or are you using the native tethering in Android 2.2 and up?

What phone? Is it custom ROM? Is it rooted?

Comment: Yes, good clarification on the terminology! I've added some more information at the top, to answer your questions.

Comment: Better to ask clarification questions as comments on the original question. It's hard to find the answer in here.