# How to use my phone to transfer Wi-Fi to other devices?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, wifi-tethering, ad-hoc-networks

I'm using Nexus S, recently I got a Kindle, however, the Kindle couldn't connect to my company's Wi-Fi (seems it doesn't support the encryption method), so I'm wondering this method:

1. My Nexus S connect to company's Wi-Fi
2. Nexus S performs like a adhoc  , create a new wifi
3. Kindle connect to the new Wi-Fi.

The problem is how to perform step 2. I found a software `Wifi tether`, but it can only tether 3G network to other devices, not Wi-Fi.

Any suggestions? my phone is rooted.

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to share a Wi-Fi via Wi-Fi, this would require two Wi-Fi chips. Only mobile data tethering is supported via Wi-Fi.

Comment: Not exactly, Windows 7 can do this through some trickery, but I would agree that you can't do it on Android as of yet.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that Win7 can only extend the wifi, not "tether" it. Oh well, live and learn...

Comment: @onik, something doesn't make sense. If I connect the phone to the network using WiFi and then connect a laptop to it using USB tethering it still does not work. This doesn't need two WiFi cards, does it? The connection is established up to the gateway, but I cannot access anything beyond that (hence no internet connection). Any ideas?

Comment: @Gili As far as I know, no device supports reverse tethering over WiFi out of the box, and I can't find any apps for it with a quick search.

Comment: @onik, I'm not trying to do reverse tethering (to me this means sharing my Laptop's WiFi connection with the phone). I'm trying to share the **phone's** WiFi connection with the laptop.

Comment: @Gili Ah, yes. My bad. But still, most devices only have mobile network tethering built in, but it's possible, at least with a 3rd party app.